# How to connect a servo motor and a crank shaft

Tags: arduino, mechanism, rcservo

I have a standard 5v

[image]

I am using the horn it came with it, I mean this piece:

[image]

Like the long arm in the middle. Each of its holes are 1mm diameter.

Then I have a 3d printed crankshaft I did:

[image]

Its holes are also 1 mm. So while the servo horn is attached to the servo, I attach this crank to the horn in order to lift or lower a small scructure.

What I am not sure is hot to connect these 2 pieces (horn and 3d printed crankshaft). So far I have been using a paper clip, and at both end of it I placed 2 blobs of tin using a soldering iron. This has worked for nearly a year, but today I failed, and I was wondering if there's something more specific for my problem, which seems something common.

I have seen some people use something called Dubro EZ connector, but it seems an overkill, plus it won't have space for my 3D printed piece. Some people seems to use a clevis pin, but I cannot find any with a diameter of less than 1.

So my question is, how can I fix it? What can I put at both ends to stop if from slipping away? I have already tried simple things like simply bending it.

Comment: Why wouldn't a nut and bolt work in this situation?  Why isn't drilling a larger hole an option?  If clevis pins aren't available in such a small size, did you look at retaining rings (circlips)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I cannot use bolt and nut because I need the bolt to be flat in order to allow for rotation. I can get bolts with a flat part, but not as small as I need. Regarding the circlips, thank you, I didn't know they existed, but I am having a similar problem, because I need like 1 mm diameter.

Comment: Rivets might also be something to check out.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I had to check what's a rivet. it seems I would need a gun, which I don't have, and they might tight too tightly.

Comment: @DrSokoban, did you finally come up with a solution? If so, do not hesitate to write up an answer for your own question. This way, future visitors would also benefit from your solution.

Comment: @Shahbaz I didnt. Still using the old crappy system. I am welcome for new alternatives.